# Cross Reference Excel Data between Different Sheets and Highlight the Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting, cross-reference

I have a workbook with 10 sheets of machine parts. On sheet 10, I am going to have the critical parts listed. I want to reference all of the information on sheet 10 in columns A-I, and I want to then highlight the row for every other instance in the workbook. 
For example. If I have SAP number "829131" on sheet 10. I want every row that has SAP number "829131" in the entire workbook to be highlighted.

I have no idea where to even start with this. So hopefully you can help me out.

I found something online that I thought I would work, but it only references the active cell and I can't figure out how to make it reference the range I need it to.

```
Sub CriticalSpare()

'Code will highlight all rows in all open workbooks
'which contain the same text as active cell
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fString As String
Dim firstAdd As String
Dim fCell As Range
Dim myCol As Long

'The item to look for is the active cell
fString = ActiveCell.Value

'Highlight things in red
myCol = 41


'Don't run on a blank cell
If fString = "" Then
     MsgBox "No value given"
     Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Loop through all workbooks...
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
'...and all worksheets
     For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         Set fCell = Nothing
            firstAdd = ""
         With ws.Cells
             'looking for the desired value
            Set fCell = .Find(fString)
             If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
                    firstAdd = fCell.Address
                   Do
                      'and if found, highlight the row
                    fCell.Interior.ColorIndex = myCol
                        Set fCell = .FindNext(fCell)
                  Loop Until fCell.Address = firstAdd
               End If
         End With
        Next ws
Next wb
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like Conditional Formatting would work.

Comment: I thought about using Conditional Formatting after reading some stuff online, but I couldn't find anything that would work for my situation. If that would work though, I am willing to try it. Ill add an edit to the original post that goes over what I have already done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit this code to meet your needs.  Paste it into the ThisWorkbook code as it handles the selection change event

The following procedure highlights the entire row and column at each new cell selection:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myRow As Long, myColumn As Long

myRow = Target.Row
myColumn = Target.Column

Sh.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Sh.Rows(myRow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Sh.Columns(myColumn).Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```